# Sublime Text 3 SFTP

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using the SFTP plugin for sublime text 3, and when editing a remote file I get this annoying error message:

A sftp-config.json file was not found in "directorypath" or any parent folders

What do i need to do to stop this message from poping up?

I searched the [website for SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) and could not find any reference to this error or what it means.

Comment: Possibly you need to check the SFTP modules Website http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp for sublime. If that's the module you use.

Comment: create a file `sftp-config.json` and put it in the root folder

Comment: @meda do we know what goes in that file?

Comment: the sftp settings see here http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings#Settings for example http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/img/sftp/remote_config.png

Comment: The directory path that this error is referencing is in the tmp folder... do I have to manually add a sftp-config.json file to my tmp folder every time i want to use this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem, and I will share my experience here:
The error popped up right after I performed a "Save as". it took me a while to notice what happened because I had many tabs open and many were using SFTP. what actually happened was sublime was reading the file from the new location that I just "saved as" which was local and so SFTP was looking for the file in a wrong location. therefor I just closed the tab, and reopened my file from server and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @ManavSinghGadhoke luck with what? I don't know anything more than what I wrote here, I thought maybe other people would face the same issue. if this is not the case for you, then maybe after you solved your problem come back and write your answer for others to see.